# mysql function exists but I get a `1305 FUNCTION slurm_acct_db.sys_exec does not exist` error. Why?

Tags: mysql, function

I have a mysql database. I have installed the following library [lib_mysqludf_sys][1] and created the function.

I can list the functions with:

```
mysql> select * from mysql.func;
+-----------------------+-----+---------------------+----------+
| name                  | ret | dl                  | type     |
+-----------------------+-----+---------------------+----------+
| lib_mysqludf_sys_info |   0 | lib_mysqludf_sys.so | function |
| sys_get               |   0 | lib_mysqludf_sys.so | function |
| sys_set               |   2 | lib_mysqludf_sys.so | function |
| sys_exec              |   2 | lib_mysqludf_sys.so | function |
| sys_eval              |   0 | lib_mysqludf_sys.so | function |
+-----------------------+-----+---------------------+----------+
```

with sys.exec clearly showing up. Yet I get the following error.

```
 mysql_query failed: 1305 FUNCTION slurm_acct_db.sys_exec does not exist
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

**Update**

So if i do:

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE db = 'slurm_acct_db';
```

I get an empty set - so the function isn't there. It is in the func table of the database mysql, i.e. `mysql.func`.

I guess it is put there by default.

So how to I either move it to a database of my choice, or call it from mysql.func?

It is in
[1]: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys

Comment: Does current account is granted to execute this function?

Comment: I think so - I have run

`GRANT EXECUTE ON *.* TO 'slurm'@'%'`